# Find the differential equation described by the family

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the differential equation described the family of curves $y = kx^2$

So obviously, $y' = 2kx$

**But why must the answer** include $y$?

Isn't $y' = 2kx$ a perfectly valid answer? The book writes

> $y' = 2\sqrt{ky}$

Why?

Comment: I would be confused - but at the same time, if you write a differential equation as $f(y',y)$ then you can plot a phase -plane diagram which captures the qualitative behaviour as well. Though this is me clutching at straws

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your answer (although I would specify initial conditions to get rid of the floating constant of integration).

Answer (score 0):

$$y=kx^2 \implies \frac {y}{x^2}=k $$

$$\implies \frac {y'x^2-2xy}{x^4}=0$$

$$\implies  x y'=2y $$